# How to add background color for word in PDF using PDF::API2?

Tags: perl, pdf

I am extracting words left, top, right,bottom from xml and i created pdf but i want  to add background color for the words.

Comment: what did you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out **Colors** section in the documentation of [PDF::API2::Content](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::API2::Content#Colors).

```
$content->fillcolor('blue');
```